# Is it a scam if a persons asks for my name, email address, bank name, age and nationality?

Tags: fraud

In return for being his personal assistant and replying to emails and stuff, a man said that  he'll pay me weekly.  He told me to send him a screenshot after emailing his clients.  He also sent me his identity card.

Another lady asked me to send her scratched steam gift cards and she'll pay me the money with an extra $100. All she asked for is my full name, email address, and bank name.

Are they scammers?

Comment: Yeah its a scam. Anything like this were you are basically getting free money or lots of money for very little work is a scam.

Comment: I wonder what it takes to understand that a stranger asking for your personal information and offering you free money isn't on the up and up?

Answer (score 2):

This is an [advaned fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam) together with [identity theft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theft) (with the victims consents) fraud.

The scammer simply tricks the victims to give them the cash voucher card number and vanished. Thanks to [sunk cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost) effect, some scammer can continue to skim money from the gullible victims, as the victims continue to give the money with the hope of getting even more money in return, which will never happened.

Comment: she sent me a cheque though

Comment: @tilalaping , the cheque will almost certainly be rejected when the banks cannot get paid for it (because it has fictitious routing and account numbers). This will most certainly happen in several weeks.